# Python Parser Recursion Infinite Reference

Tags: python, parsing, recursion

Im new to Parsers and i have a problem with my Parser, specifically when i call itself to analize the body of a function.

When it finds another function, just became crazy and messy.

Basically, when analyzing this code

```
fn test (a, b, c):
    fn test2 (c, b, a):
        print("Hello world")
    end
end
```

It starts to point the object to itself, not the subfunction:

```
>>> print(ast[0].value.body[9])
<ast.VariableAST object at 0x7f6285540710>  
>>> print(ast[0].value.body[9].value.body[9])
<ast.VariableAST object at 0x7f6285540710>
```

This is the main parser code:

```
# Parser Loop
def Parser(tokenList):
    global tokens
    global size
    tokens = tokenList
    size = len(tokens)
    ast = []
    while i < size:
        ast.append(MainParser())
    return ast


# The Main Parser
def MainParser():
    global i
    if tokens[i] == 'fn':
        i += 1
        node = FunctionParser()
    else:
        node = tokens[i]
        i += 1
    return node


# Parse a function
def FunctionParser():
    global i
    checkEnd("function")
    if tokens[i][0].isalpha():
        node = VariableAST()
        node.name = tokens[i]
        i += 1
        node.value = FunctionBodyParser()
    elif tokens[i] == '(':
        node = FunctionBodyParser()
    else:
        syntaxError("Expecting '(' or function name")
    return node


# Parse a function body
def FunctionBodyParser():
    global i
    i += 1
    node = FunctionAST()
    while True:
        checkEnd("function")
        if tokens[i][0].isalpha():
            node.args.append(tokens[i])
            i += 1
        elif tokens[i] == ',':
            i += 1
        elif tokens[i] == ')':
            break
        else:
            syntaxError("Expecting ')' or ',' in function declaration")
    i += 1
    checkEnd("function")
    if tokens[i] != ':' and tokens[i] != '{':
        syntaxError("Expecting '{' or ':'")
    begin = tokens[i]
    while True:
        checkEnd("function")
        if begin == ':' and tokens[i] == 'end':
            break
        elif begin == '{' and tokens[i] == '}':
            break
        else:
            node.body.append(MainParser())
    i += 1
    return node
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is a prototype for a C version. Im avoiding stuff related to object orientation and some good pratices in python to make easier to port the code to C later.

Comment: Before going much further, and regardless of whether you are going to use a parsing library or write from scratch, write up a BNF of the language you are planning to parse. Create a series of test cases from very simple to complex, and make sure the BNF describes them properly. This will serve as a roadmap as you implement your parser, and will help you know when you are done (or at least ready for your next language extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

Actually it was a silly error of programming in Python and the above parser is working fine.

In AST i was creating classes like structure to make easier to port the language to C. But i was doing it wrong, for example:

```
class VariableAST(NodeAST):
    name = None
    value = None
```

What i didnt knew about Python is that those parameters inside the class arent attributes for the object, but static variables, wich just made my program work unpredictable when i assing a value to a object, since im assing to a static variable, i also assing to all other variables and theres is my infinite recursion of objects.

Comment: For them to be instance variables, you have to create a method, usually `def __init__(self):`, and assign them as `self.name = None` and `self.value = None`.  This should be covered in most Python tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of parser implemented in Python https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing like [PyPEG](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/) allowing you to describe the language you're parsing instead of parsing it yourself, which is more readable and less error-prone.

Also using `global` is typically a source of problems as you can't control the scope of a variable (there's only one), reducing reusability of your functions.

It's probably better to use a class, which is almost the same thing but you can have multiple instances of the same class running at the same time without variable colisions:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, tokenList):
        self.tokens = tokenList
        self.size = len(tokenList)
        self.ast = []
        self.position = 0

    def parse(tokenList):
        while self.position < self.size:
            self.ast.append(self.main())
        return self.ast

    def main(self):
        if self.tokens[self.position] == 'fn':
            self.position += 1
            node = self.function()
        else:
            node = self.tokens[self.position]
            self.position += 1
        return node

    # And so on...
```

From this point you can deduplicate self.position += 1 in main:

```
    def main(self):
        self.position += 1
        if self.tokens[self.position] == 'fn':
            node = self.function()
        else:
            node = self.tokens[self.position]
        return node
```

Then remove the useless "node" variable:

```
    def main(self):
        self.position += 1
        if self.tokens[self.position] == 'fn':
            return self.function()
        else:
            return self.tokens[self.position]
```

But the real way to do this is to use a parser, take a look a pyPEG, it's a nice one, but others are nice too.

Oh and last point, avoid useless comments like:

```
# Parse a function
def FunctionParser():
```

We know that "FunctionParser" "Parse a function", thanks, that's *not* an information. The most important is to wisely choose your function names (oh, the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) tells us not to start method name with capitalized letters), and if you want to add meta-information about the function, put it in a string as a first statement in your function like:

```
def functionParser():
    "Delegates the body parsing to functionBodyParser"
```

Comment: Hello my friend,

I should tell this in the topic (i will edit), this is a prototype for a C version, wich i dont have access to classes or any parser builder (im kinda avoiding that because the propuse of the language). But thanks anyway, and i will use some tips that you passed me.

Comment: @h0m3 Are you seriously telling me no parser exists in C ? There's A LOT of them : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators, there's probably more parsers in C than in Python. Some (like ANTLR3) can even produce from the same description C AND Python so you can test use the same code in your Python tests and real C impl.

Comment: Of course, you're completly right. The parser i want to do myself for learning propuses and for code size (the language is pretty simple and i want to keep it smallest as possible. And i think, not at the beguinning, but when i learn more, the parser can actually be smaller than one made by a parser generator). Im trying to avoid using anything beyond the C lib.

Comment: Smaller, but slower, if you don't learn a few months / years about parsing (LR parsers, LL parsers, LALR, lookahead, PEG, and so on, so many subjects to explore here).But I agree that's an interesting subject to learn from, you'll have plenty of room for rewriting / optimizations.

Comment: Yeah. It will be pretty crappy at first. For now, im just learning the basics of LL parsers only. But for learning purpose and future optimization i think thats better to learn how to parse than just use a parse generator.